# How to get a vector containing only the last n elements of another vector?

Tags: c++

I have an `std::vector`, and I want a separate `std::vector` containing only the last n elements of the original vector.  Besides a loop over the entire vector inserting one-by-one, is there a cleaner way of doing this?

Comment: @sshekhar: *"a loop over the entire vector inserting one-by-one"*

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
int n = 5;
std::vector<int> x = ...;
std::vector<int> y(x.end() - n, x.end());
```

Of course, this will crash and burn if `x.size()` < `n`

To elaborate a little, `std::vector` (like most of the standard library containers) has a constructor which takes a pair of iterators. It fills the vector with all the items from the first iterator up to the second.

Comment: You can bullt-proof this `std:vector<int> y(x.end() - std::min(x.size(), n), x.end());`

Comment: I had to specify `<int>` in my case: `std:vector<int> y(x.end() - std::min<int>(x.size(), n), x.end());`.

Answer (score 2):

You can construct `copyVector` directly using the two iterator constructor:

```
std::vector<int> original = ...;
std::vector<int>::iterator start = std::next(original.begin(), M);
std::vector<int> copyVector(start, original.end());
```

or use `std::vector`'s [assign](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/assign) method:

```
std::vector<int>::iterator start = std::next(original.begin(), M);
std::vector<int> copyVector = ... ;
...
copyVector.assign(start, original.end());
```

where `M` is calculated from `original.size()` and `n`.

Comment: But there's no need to use `back_inserter` because `vector` already comes with an iterator constructor and assign method.

Comment: @MarkB yes, I added an example using the two iterator constructor. std::vector::assign is another option.

Comment: `std::advance` doesn't return anything as it's return type is `void`. You need to set 
`std::vector<int>::iterator start = original.begin()` and then do `std::advance(start, M)`

Comment: @Matic Good catch, thanks! I meant `std::next`. It is fixed now.

Comment: Also, if wanna use `std::next` instead of `operator-` for some reason(e.g. bidirectional iterator), we can just `std::next(original.end(), -n)`, such as `copyVector.assign(std::next(original.end(), -n), original.end())`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get, say, the last 10 elements from a 20-element vector, you can do it like so:

```cpp
int n = 10;
std::vector<float> x(3.14, 20); // 20-element vector of 3.14s
std::vector<float> y(x.end() - std::min<int>(x.size(), n), x.end());
```